# Is there a way to script a schema with SQL Management?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssms

Is there a way to script a Schema (that currently exists) to a script in SQL Management (similar to how you scrip a table)?

Comment: did you mean create schema with script ??

Comment: I mean there is a pre-existing schema in my database (that I did not create) and I want to be able to duplicate that schema and place it in a different database.  I would also like to see the settings of that schema as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Security -> Schemas -> SelectedSchema -> Script schema as...

Comment: Where is the Security option located?  I am using SSMS 2008.

Comment: It took a while...I thought the Security was a menu option....but it was actually the folder in that database.  That worked.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script to create a temp schema in mydatabase. However, you will need to know the authorization!

```
USE [mydatabase]
GO
CREATE SCHEMA [temp] AUTHORIZATION [myautorisation]
```